# Should I use an LSTM model when the outcome is a different variable from the training data?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm

I am trying to model a health outcome as a function of climate variables.  I have many observations of health outcomes at different times and locations (but NOT a sequence at one location). For each health observation, I have the temperature and rainfall for every month before the health observation up to 24 months.  Lets say I have 25,000 observations.

So my outcome is the shape `(25000, )` and each is a rate from 0 to 1.

My predictors are the shape `(25000, 24, 2)`, i.e., 24000 observations, over 24 months, for two features.

In trying to get a sense of what neural network architecture I should use, I keep coming across LSTMs.  However, most applications seem to use a times series of some training variable (say, stocks prices, rainfall levels, or a sequence of text) to learn trends and the make predictions of *that same variable*.  But I want use weather data to predict a *different* variable, and my outcome is a single value (not a sequence).

Is LSTM appropriate for this application?  If not, what type of architecture should I look into here?

Answer (score 0):

LSTM (and GRUs, and Recurrent Neural Networks more generally) predict the next item $x_n$ in a sequence X of items $[x_1, ..., x_{n-1}]$, as you mentionned.

However, you can combine them with a feed forward network (as simple as a perceptron), either as a separate layer or a new network, to take the prediction at each set (the $x_i$) and from this $x_i$ predict your two variables/features ($y_{i1}$ and ${y_i2}$).

You would train both layers/networks jointly, one on predicting $x_i$ from $[x_1, ..., x_{i-1}]$ and the other on predicting $y_{i1}$ and $y_{i2}$ from $x_i$.